# Hide rows in autofilter when cell is empty or 0?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to hide each rows in autofilter when the criteria cell is empty or 0. Is this possible to do?

This is my best attempt, but it doesn't work:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1 _
    :="<>0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it but you need to use `xlAnd` like this:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, 
    Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
```

Default `Operator` argument is `xlAnd` so you can omit is as well

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, _
    Criteria1:="<>0", Criteria2:="<>"
```